# windows phone empty dynamic link library : visual C++

Tags: dll, windows-phone-8, transplant

Does any one know about this type of windows phone 8 project in vs 2012? windows phone empty dynamic link library  ,  visual C++

I build a project of this type and produced a dll, then I tried to add this dll as a reference only to get this message: A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.

I have tried both win32 and arm platform.

Comment: A C# project can only reference a windows phone runtime component. Wrap your class(es) in a winphone rt component then you'll be able to reference that.

Comment: I see, only C++ projects can reference this kind of dll.

Comment: But my project is not standard C++, is C++\CLI, windows phone runtime component doesn't seem to support CLR?